# How to configure searchable activity when applicationId differs from package id?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-search

I've changed applicationId and after that search functionality in my application stopped working. I initiate search via:

```
activity.onSearchRequested();
```

Essential part of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androzic" >

    <application
        android:name=".Androzic"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".SearchableActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/search_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Essential part of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androzic.v2"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```

How do I properly configure search if my applicationId is not the same as package id?

Comment: what applicationId are you referring to?

Comment: where do you use that `applicationId` ? is is a part of the manifest?

Comment: No, it's a part of build.gradle:

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.androzic.v2"
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 105
            versionName "2.0.3"
        }
    }

Comment: Is not `package` definition ignored when `applicationId` is set? Did you try to use same package name as in `applicationId` in `xml/searchable.xml`?

Comment: @ozbek I didn't find any way to specify package in `searchable.xml`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm... Is not there something like `<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:value="com.androzic.SearchableActivity"`?

Comment: @ozbek No, couldn't find

Comment: Right, just noticed that that's not in official docs. If you are not declaring full package name for `searchSuggestAuthority` then sorry I am out of clue.

Comment: you still using a content provider aren't you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specified applicationId with other value than package attribute, it's safe to set **full qualified class name** as android:value of meta-data element, like below.

```xml
<activity
        android:name="com.androzic.SearchableActivity"
        .../>
```

or

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value="com.androzic.SearchableActivity" />
```

Comment: I will not verify this solution as the question is outdated but it looks like this is what I was searching for. So I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write this before `</application>`

```
<meta-data
android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
```